# How to extend the TestEnvironment of a ZIO Test

Tags: scala, zio, zio-test

I want to test the following function:

```
def curl(host: String, attempt: Int = 200): ZIO[Loggings with Clock, Throwable, Unit]
```

If the environment would just use standard ZIO environments, like `Console with Clock`, the test would work out of the box:

```
testM("curl on valid URL") {
      (for {
        r <- composer.curl("https://google.com")
      } yield
        assert(r, isUnit))
    }
```

The Test environment would be provided by `zio-test`.

So the question is, how to extend the TestEnvironment with my `Loggings` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this answer is for RC17 and will change significantly in RC18. You're right that as in other cases of composing environments we need to implement a function to build our total environment from the modules we have. Spec has several combinators built in such as `provideManaged` to do this so you don't need to do it within your test itself. All of these have "normal" variants that will provide a separate copy of the environment to each test in a suite and "shared" variants that will create one copy of the environment for the entire suite when it is a resource that is expensive to create like a Kafka service.

You can see an example below of using `provideSomeManaged` to provide an environment that extends the test environment to a test.

In RC18 there will be a variety of other provide variants equivalent to those on ZIO as well as a new concept of layers to make it much easier to build composed environments for ZIO applications.

```scala
import zio._
import zio.clock._
import zio.test._
import zio.test.environment._

import ExampleSpecUtil._

object ExampleSpec
    extends DefaultRunnableSpec(
      suite("ExampleSpec")(
        testM("My Test") {
          for {
            time <- clock.nanoTime
            _ <- Logging.logLine(
              s"The TestClock says the current time is $time"
            )
          } yield assertCompletes
        }
      ).provideSomeManaged(testClockWithLogging)
    )

object ExampleSpecUtil {

  trait Logging {
    def logging: Logging.Service
  }

  object Logging {

    trait Service {
      def logLine(line: String): UIO[Unit]
    }

    object Live extends Logging {
      val logging: Logging.Service =
        new Logging.Service {
          def logLine(line: String): UIO[Unit] =
            UIO(println(line))
        }
    }

    def logLine(line: String): URIO[Logging, Unit] =
      URIO.accessM(_.logging.logLine(line))
  }

  val testClockWithLogging
      : ZManaged[TestEnvironment, Nothing, TestClock with Logging] =
    ZIO
      .access[TestEnvironment] { testEnvironment =>
        new TestClock with Logging {
          val clock = testEnvironment.clock
          val logging = Logging.Live.logging
          val scheduler = testEnvironment.scheduler
        }
      }
      .toManaged_
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up:

```
testM("curl on valid URL") {
      (for {
        r <- composer.curl("https://google.com")
      } yield
        assert(r, isUnit))
        .provideSome[TestEnvironment](env => new Loggings.ConsoleLogger
           with TestClock {
           override val clock: TestClock.Service[Any] = env.clock
           override val scheduler: TestClock.Service[Any] = env.scheduler
           override val console: TestLogger.Service[Any] = MyLogger()
      })
    }
```

Using the `TestEnvironment` with `provideSome` to setup my environment.